# Converting a numeric value to date time

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, sql-server-2012, type-conversion

I am working in SQL Server 2012. My date column in a data set looks like this: `41547`. The column is in `nvarchar (255)`. I want to convert it to something like this: `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` (Example: `2013-09-14 12:23:23.98933090`). But I can not do this. I am using following code:

```
select convert(datetime, date_column, 6)
```

But this is giving following error:

```
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Conversion failed when converting
date and/or time from character string.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just found the way to do this.

First I have to covert the nvarchar to int then I have to convert it to date time. I have used following code:

```
Select convert(datetime, (convert (int, [date_column])), 6) as 'convertedDateTime' from mytable
```

Answer (score 16):

Your date is actually a numeric value (float or integer), stored in a char column. So, you need to convert it to a numerical value (in this case, to `float`) first, like:

```
select convert(datetime, CONVERT(float,date_column))
```

A value of `41547.5` will result in:

```
`2013-10-02 12:00:00`
```

The style argument, in your case `6` is only necessary when converting from or to char-types. In this case it is not needed and will be ignored.

---

NB: The float value is the number of days since `1900-01-01`.

e.g. `select convert(datetime, CONVERT(float,9.0))` => `1900-01-10 00:00:00`; the same as `select dateadd(day,9.0,'1900-01-01')` would.

The decimal part of the number also equates to days; so `0.5` is half a day / 12 hours.

e.g. `select convert(datetime, CONVERT(float,.5))` => `1900-01-01 12:00:00`.  (Here our comparison to dateadd doesn't make sense, since that only deals with integers rather than floats).

Comment: thanks. However I converted the date column to int not flot. I think this will give the same value like yours.

Answer (score 1):

There is an easier way to do it as well.

```
select convert(date,cast (date_Column+ 19000000 as nvarchar(10)))
    as date_Column_Formated
  from table_Name
```

Answer (score 0):

6 format is: "dd mon yy"
Like this: SELECT convert(datetime, '23 OCT 16', 6)
Other formats will cause your error

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(INT,date_column))
```