# How to get Sale data of every month of a year

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to get Sale Data of every month of particular year, but I'm having a problem building a query for it.

Here is What I've tried

```
SELECT COUNT(`id`) AS `total_order`
FROM orders
WHERE date BETWEEN ? AND ?
GROUP BY `total_order`
```

HERE is How my table look like

```
----------------------------------------
| id | item_name | amount | time       |
| 21 | item_1    | 10     | 1506675630 |
| 22 | item_2    | 30     | 1506675630 |
| 23 | item_3    | 70     | 1506675630 |
| 24 | item_4    | 100    | 1506675630 |
----------------------------------------
```

Now here is what i want from the query

```
1 - Total Sales amount made from the beginning of the year till today.
2 - Sales made Today
3 - Sales made in Last Month
4 - Sales Made in Last 3 month
5 - Sales Made in Last 6 Month
6 - Total Number of Sales made in every month of this particular year
```

for e.g -
January - 20
Feb -100
March - 200 & so on.

How can i achieve this complex query?

Comment: i found this link for convert the numeric number in a date: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19271007/converting-a-numeric-value-to-date-time

Comment: add time column as date like @Alberslash said

Comment: I feel that you are actually asking for diferent querys. You can't represent diferent time groupings in the same query . Also it feels like you are asking us to make the query for you, your atempt is not even close at what it should look like, I wonder if it even makes logical sense.

Comment: Lack of research, The code you provided doesn't do anything with the given tasks. 1-5 can be easily found on google. even 6th one too.

Comment: @SaadSuri I already know that, I'm looking a way to integrate all 5 task in one single query

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT `id` AS `Order_Number`, item_name, SUM(Amount)
    FROM orders
    WHERE time >= '01/01/17'
    GROUP BY date
```

That would give you your first result. Try the others and let me know what you get

Comment: That GROUP BY is invalid, will return an unpredictable result in older MySQL versions, will raise an error in new versions (unless in compatibility mode.) The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function.

Comment: Surely using ORDER BY 1 is potentially unpredictable too or especially in my line of work. What happens if someone adds another column

Comment: Yeah, ORDER BY ordinal-position was removed from the ANSI SQL standard more than 20 years ago. (And GROUP BY ordinal-position has never been in the standard.)

Comment: so what about the other answer? that uses ordinal positioning?

Comment: Hey, MySQL question, MySQL answer... Sure, 'ORDER BY 1' is no standard SQL, but I don't see any requirement in the question. If it gets the job done, you get paid...

Answer (score 0):

This answers your first question

```
SELECT
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(time), '%Y-%m') as interval,
COUNT(*) AS sales_made,
SUM(amount) AS sales_amount
FROM orders
WHERE
time BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2017-01-01') AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-01-01')
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

Comment: there is an error in your sql query - you have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'interval, COUNT(*) AS sales_made,

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i think would work:

for the first 5 queries try something like this.

```
SELECT SUM(amount)
    FROM orders
    WHERE DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`orders.time`), '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

And for the last one you'll need :

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`orders.time`), '%Y-%m-%d') AS 'date', SUM(amount)
        FROM orders
        WHERE date between ? AND ?
        GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y%m')
```

You can try without the FROM_UNIXTIME if it doesnt work.